# Find a response vector that minimizes the distance to the true line

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I have a system of equation of the following form:

$$ {\bf W} \vec{x} = \vec{y} $$

W is a thin matrix (i.e. has more rows than columns) and $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$ are vectors of appropriate size.

I solved this equation using the pseudo-inverse:

$$ \vec{x} = ({\bf W})^\dagger \  \vec{y} $$

We know that by definition the pseudo-inverse gave the solution that minimized: $$|| {\bf W} \vec{x} - \vec{y}||$$

However, now that I found the values of my vector $\vec{x}$, I would like to find the maximum amount of change that I could apply to the vector $\vec{y}$ that would keep the values of $\vec{x}$ constant and would minimize the distance $|| {\bf W} \vec{x} - \vec{y}|| = || {\bf W} \vec{x} -  \vec{y}||$ further.

Is there any way that I could find an analytical solution to this problem?

**Clarification:**: Let $\epsilon =  || {\bf W} \vec{x} -   \vec{y}||$.

I have two steps to my problem: First I would like to find my response variable $\vec{x}$ which I simply find by calculating $({\bf W})^\dagger \  \vec{y}$. **Now**, my problem arises here.

After this step and getting my value $\vec{y}$, I would now like to change the values of $\vec{y}$ to reduce $\epsilon$ while keeping the values of $\vec{x}$ constant.

Edit 1: fixed a typo, the solution to the system is simple the pseudo-inverse of ${\bf W}$ and not the ${\bf W}^T$.

Edit 2: added a clarification.

Comment: Your pseudoinverse solution has an erroneous transpose and is dimensionally  incompatible. The general solution is $$x=W^+y + (I-W^+W)z$$ where $z$ is an arbitrary vector. The minimal length of $x$ coincides with $z=0$.

Comment: If you consider $y$ to be a function of $x$, the solution becomes
$$y=Wx + (I-WW^+)u$$ where $u$ is arbitrary. You can vary $y$ by $(I-WW^+)u$ without affecting the value of $x$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, the transpose was a typo, just fixed it, there is no dimensionality mismatch in that case right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that the residual doesn't change at all simply by moving along a level set. Assume this path is of the form y+f(tau), f(0)=0, simply calculate the gradient of the residual with respect to tau and set to 0: grad ((y+f)'(y+f) - 2(y+f)'Wx + x'W'Wx) = 0 => 2f_t'f + 2f_t'y - 2f_t'Wx = 0 => f_t'(f+y-Wx) = 0

So simply find any vector valued function of tau such that the above is satisfied, then you'll have a level set and the residual will be unchanged.

Comment: I guess to better put it : I want to reduce the residuals as much as I can without changing the values of $\vec{x}$ but only by the values of $\vec{y}$.

Comment: then set y = Wx